# How do I get the network speed of a VLAN

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following URL to retrieve information on network VLANs.

[https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans.json?objectMask=mask[subnetCount,subnets.virtualGuestCount,subnets.hardwareCount,subnets.billingItem.pendingCancellationFlag,sanStorageCapabilityFlag,primaryRouter,primaryRouter.datacenter,dedicatedFirewallFlag,firewallRuleCount,networkVlanFirewall[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,firewallType],attachedNetworkGateway[members[hardware[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystemReferenceCode,operatingSystem[softwareLicense[softwareDescription[manufacturer]]]]]]]](https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans.json?objectMask=mask%5BsubnetCount,subnets.virtualGuestCount,subnets.hardwareCount,subnets.billingItem.pendingCancellationFlag,sanStorageCapabilityFlag,primaryRouter,primaryRouter.datacenter,dedicatedFirewallFlag,firewallRuleCount,networkVlanFirewall%5Bid,fullyQualifiedDomainName,firewallType%5D,attachedNetworkGateway%5Bmembers%5Bhardware%5Bid,fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystemReferenceCode,operatingSystem%5BsoftwareLicense%5BsoftwareDescription%5Bmanufacturer%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D)

I am trying to get the VLAN network speed like 100Mbps, 1000Mbps, or 10000Mbps of the VLAN. What mask do I use to get the network speed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your mask:

```
networkComponentTrunks[networkComponent]
```